# Getting "unixtime" in Java

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

Date.getTime() returns milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. Unixtime is seconds since Jan 1, 1970. I don't usually code in java, but I'm working on some bug fixes. I have:

```
Date now = new Date();      
Long longTime = new Long(now.getTime()/1000);
return longTime.intValue();
```

Is there a better way to get unixtime in java?

Comment: Since you're cast it to an int, you've introduced the year 2038 problem (the equivalent of Y2K for Unix).  That's when Unix epoch hits 2 billion and rolls over to negative.  The fix is to move to 64-bit Unix.  The Java equivalent is to leave it as a long.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The code this is interfacing with is expecting a 32bit int for unixtime.

Comment: 2038 is coming soon.

Comment: Is there a proper name or standard for currentTimeMillis?  I tend to refer to it in my documentation as the millisecond version of UNIX time.

Comment: I believe a formal version which everyone would aknowledge is: current time in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

Comment: I tend to use epoch seconds and epoch milliseconds.  That's clear enough.  What other epoch could there possibly be?

Comment: @jettero `What other epoch could there be?` There are at least about [20 other epochs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Multiply that by the fact that some libraries count seconds (Unix), some milliseconds (java.util.Date, Joda-Time DateTime), some microseconds, and some nanoseconds (java.time). And factor in 32-bit versus 64-bit numbers. That adds up to a mess. Best to avoid count-from-epoch. Instead serialize to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as: `2014-07-11T04:22:46Z`.

Answer (score 539, accepted):

Avoid the Date object creation w/ [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).  A divide by 1000 gets you to Unix epoch.

As mentioned in a comment, you typically want a primitive long (lower-case-l long) not a boxed object long (capital-L Long) for the unixTime variable's type.

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Comment: Also consider using primitive long instead of autoboxing to Long, unless you want to handle the number as an Object (like put it into a Collection), again avoids unnecessary object creation

Comment: The Java 32-bit int matches 32-bit platforms (and the year 2038 problem).  64-bit platforms use a larger time_t data type.  Java dodged that bullet by using a long as the return for System.currentTimeMillis().  If you convert to int, you're re-introducing the year 2038 problem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions

Comment: What happens if this division returns a fractional number? is it automatically rounded?

Comment: @ClickUpvote The numerator and denominator are both longs, so it's integer division.

Comment: I think you are mistaken on one point: There is no difference between a lower case "L" and an upper case one when using them in numeric literals like this.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Comment: The capitalization discussion (clarified above) was about the data type. Primitive "long" vs "java.lang.Long" class instance.  You're talking about the suffix letter on the long literal, which I agree can be upper or lower case. Though lower case "l" looks a heck of a lot like the digit "1" so it's much more readable to use capital "L".

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't account for other timezones. For instance, the above code returns 13:00 but should return 15:00

Comment: Click the link to the documentation. The return is defined as number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 in the UTC timezone. You want timezones? Look at java.util.Calendar.

Comment: Also note you can use `DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND` (Apache) or `DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS` (Android) instead of 1000L to make it a little cleaner.

Answer (score 322):

Java 8 added a new API for working with dates and times. 
With Java 8 you can use

```
import java.time.Instant
...
long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

`Instant.now()` returns an [Instant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) that represents the current system time. With `getEpochSecond()` you get the epoch seconds (unix time) from the `Instant`.

Comment: What is the difference between `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()` , `new Date().getTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: One difference is that the former is in seconds while the latter two are in milliseconds.  There may or may not be others.

Comment: `import java.time.Instant` if you are in Scala

Comment: Check this site as well for detailed description... Liked it.. [currentTimeMillis](https://currentmillis.com/tutorials/system-currentTimeMillis.html)

Comment: Note that you can not use this method with older android API Levels.

Comment: I wanted to use unix time stamp to avoid the 2038 problem. Java's source code just converts their currentMS to Unix Time Stamp not an actual implementation

Comment: What if we want milliseconds?

Answer (score 5):

There are two excellent answers already. On the occasion of a new duplicate I am diving a little deeper in two directions:

1. What to do on java 7?
2. How to write a testable version?

### For Java 7

If you are still using Java 7, you may still choose which of the other answers you want to use. Micha mentions that java.time was introduced in Java 8. But java.time has also been backported to Java 6 and 7 in the *ThreeTen Backport*. Getting the backport may seem overkill for getting a Unix timestamp, but if you are doing any more date and time work in your program, I still think that you should consider it. There’s a link at the bottom.

Also dividing by 1000 in your own code may seem a very small thing to do. Still I have made it a habit *to leave as much date and time work as possible* to the standard library, preferably java.time. There are so many other situations where a conversion seems easy but is easy to get wrong. So I don’t want to do them in my code. So my pure Java 7 solution (without an external library/backport) would probably look like this:

```
    long unixTime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(unixTime);
```

> 1636883947

Now I am also telling the reader *why* i am dividing by 1000. While the code is a little bit longer, it is also more self-explanatory.

### More testable

java.time also offers a testable solution for both Java 7 and 8 and later. We may inject a `Clock`, a source of the current time.

```
    Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();
    long unixTime = Instant.now(clock).getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println(unixTime);
```

Output just now:

> 1636882578

(I ran this on Java 1.7.0_67 using ThreeTen Backport 1.3.6.)

In a test where you need to control which time is used for a reproducible result, for example get a clock with a fixed time:

```
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_635_936_963), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Now the output from the code is the time we had specified:

> 1635936963

If all you want the `Clock` for is `Instant`s, since Java 17 no longer use `Clock`. Use `InstantSource`.

```
    InstantSource instantSource 
            = InstantSource.fixed(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_654_321_098));
    long unixTime = instantSource.instant().getEpochSecond();
```

> 1654321098

### Links

- Duplicate question [how to get the current Long timestamp value in java like 1635936963 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961434/how-to-get-the-current-long-timestamp-value-in-java-like-1635936963) asking about Java 7.
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- Question [How to test date created with LocalDateTime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527752/how-to-test-date-created-with-localdatetime-now)