# Convert integer dates/times to unix timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, android, datetime, unix-timestamp

This mainly applies to android, but could be used in Java. I have these listeners:

```
int year, month, day, hour, minute;
// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                year = year;
                month = monthOfYear;
                day = dayOfMonth;
            }
        };
// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = minute;
        }
    };
```

How could I convert `int year, month, day, hour, minute;` to a unix timestamp? Is this possible without the `Date` class?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the date class?

Comment: To avoid the Date object creation as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java

Comment: Not possible without also having user's locale!  (which I suppose you do in android, for but the general java extension, you don't have enough information in the sample to do it.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, use Calendar then, since that's preferred to Date anyway:

```
int componentTimeToTimestamp(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return (int) (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L);
}
```

Calendar won't do any computations until `getTimeMillis()` is called and is designed to be more efficient than `Date`.

Comment: Would c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0); work too? Since Calendar also has a method that takes a year, month, day of month, hour of day, minute, and second.

Comment: Not only would it work, it's more efficient, so yes setting them all with the same method call would be better still.

Comment: What about GregorianCalendar - would that be more efficient than Calendar?

Comment: @JerryBrady How is it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to avoid object overhead so I'm not suggesting any Date or Calendar classes; rather, you can calculate the value directly.

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds. ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

Calculate the number of days from Jan 1 1970 to the chosen year/month/day and multiply that by `24 * 3600`, then add `hour * 3600  +  minute * 60` to get the number of seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00 to the chosen date and time.

There are well known [algorithms](http://alcor.concordia.ca/~gpkatch/gdate-algorithm.html) for calculating the days between dates.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to account for daylight saving as well, along with local timezone, so after searching for hours all the possible solutions, what worked for me was as follows:

```
int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        int dstOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();
        long unix_timestamp = (System.currentTimeMillis() + gmtOffset + dstOffset) / 1000;
```