# What is the best way to store date/time in an SQL database on android?

Tags: java, android, sql

My question is,

What is the best way to store date/time in an SQL database on android so that the date and time can later be used for sorting the items that are getting added to the list?

Comment: I'd use UNIX TIMESTAMP (int). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java

Answer (score 3):

To easily get and store timestamp, you can use:

```
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

"It is the standard 'wall' clock (time and date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network" See more here: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
Date mDate = new Date();
```

insert in database will be `dateFormat.format(mDate)`