# Getting unix timestamp from Date()

Tags: java, date

I can convert a unix timestamp to a `Date()` object by putting the `long` value into the `Date()` constructor. For eg: I could have it as `new Date(1318762128031)`.

But after that, how can I get back the unix timestamp from the `Date()` object?

Comment: you can still get the long value of your Date object, can't u?

Comment: @xEnOn: you're not converting a Unix timestamp into a date by using the long constructor.  A Unix timestamp, as I commented on jackrabbit's answer, is expressed in seconds, not milliseconds.  Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time and here: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php    Seconds.  Not milliseconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "unixtime" in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) retrieves the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 GMT passed to the constructor. It should not be too hard to get the [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (same, but in seconds) from that.

Comment: Thanks. I kept remembering it wrongly as a static function Date.getTime(new Date()) which didn't work and thought what was going on.

Comment: @jackrabbit: actually *getTime()* doesn't give back the Unix timestamp but "Unix timestamp * 1000".  The agreed defintion about the Unix timestamp is that it gives times since the epoch in second, not milliseconds ; )

Comment: @TacticalCoder jackrabbit is more accurate: It returns the unix-timestamp in milliseconds. Yes, the unix-timestamp is agreed to be in seconds - but if your answer would be true, (`getTime() = unixTimestamp * 1000`), `getTime()` would always return three Zeros at the end, but in fact can return anything from ending with `000` to `999`, which means it has a higher precision due to milliseconds and is not just "*1000". Meaning: Comparing a real unixTimestamp*1000 with the `getTime()` result would only succeed in ~0.1% of the cases.

Comment: For the record, the function returns the miliseconds in GMT-0 area (in Greenwich), So you can be safe about converting this to different areas.

Answer (score 56):

To get a `timestamp` from `Date()`,  you'll need to divide `getTime()` by `1000`, i.e. :

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
// 1397132691
```

or simply:

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Comment: Or more tersely: `new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 26):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Timeconversion {
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm", Locale.ENGLISH); //Specify your locale

    public long timeConversion(String time) {
        long unixTime = 0;
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")); //Specify your timezone
        try {
            unixTime = dateFormat.parse(time).getTime();
            unixTime = unixTime / 1000;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return unixTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In java 8, it's convenient to use the new date lib and `getEpochSecond` method to get the timestamp (it's in second)

`Instant.now().getEpochSecond();`

Comment: But the code presented returns the # of seconds for **this** moment

Comment: True, @MilanVelebit. You will have to substitute your desired `Instant` instead of `Instant.now()`. Or `yourDesiredJavaUtilDate.toInstant()` if you got an old-fashioned `Date` from a legacy API.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you want to achieve that in js or java, in js the simplest way to get the unix timestampt (this is time in seconds from 1/1/1970) it's as follows:

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(+myDate); // +myDateObject give you the unix from that date
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class. Take a look on its javadoc: it explains how to use format switches.