# Unix timestamp creation in java

Tags: java, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting unix timestamp from Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784421/getting-unix-timestamp-from-date)

I am having the date

```
Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:40:18 GMT
```

and how should I convert it to Unix timestamp like this '1352504418' in java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Date.getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) provides 'number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00' which is the same as Unix time * 1000.

Answer (score 15):

First get the **date object**, then get the **time in millisecond(millseconds after 01/01/1970 00:00:00)**, in the end, divide the milliseconds by 1000 to get the seconds, **which is UNIX time**. You are done.

e.g.

```
    String dateString = "Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:40:18 GMT";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString );
    long unixTime = (long) date.getTime()/1000;
    System.out.println(unixTime );//<- prints 1352504418
```

Comment: if your unix time is going to be used later to get the date back from it (e.g. by Front End - JavaScript date constructor) then don't divide by 1000. it will make things complicated.