# Date to Unix timestamp

Tags: java, date, calendar, epoch

I have a string that looks like *"2015-06-07 16:01:33.0*". I want to convert it into a unix timestamp. First I use `Calendar` utility to convert it into a `Date` object. How can I convert the date to epoch time?

```
String origintime = "2015-06-07 16:01:33.0";
String year = origintime.split(" ")[0].split("-")[0];            
String month = origintime.split(" ")[0].split("-")[1];
String day = origintime.split(" ")[0].split("-")[2];

String hour = origintime.split(" ")[1].split(":")[0];
String mins = origintime.split(" ")[1].split(":")[1];
String secs = origintime.split(" ")[1].split(":")[2].replace(".0","");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(day));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(month));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(hour));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(mins));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,Integer.parseInt(secs));
String strdate = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

if (cal != null) {
    strdate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
System.out.println(strdate);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting unix timestamp from Date()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784421/getting-unix-timestamp-from-date)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many many many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can search for answers at StackOverflow, instead of posting a new question, since it make StackOverflow better, I just did a quick search and here they are: 
[Getting unix timestamp from Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784421/getting-unix-timestamp-from-date)

or here is the code that straight forward:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

Recently, people prefer jodaTime:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
long unix = dateTime.getMillis()/1000;
```

Comment: Posting an Answer to a duplicate Question only encourages more duplicate Questions and contradicts your own advice in your first sentence. Instead, use the StackOverflow feature where you request this Question be closed.

Comment: thank you Basil, I did not see the closed question features !