# Scala UTC timestamp in seconds since January 1st, 1970

Tags: scala, timestamp, utc

How do I get the Scala UTC timestamp in seconds since January 1st, 1970?

Answer (score 101):

Same way as you would in Java:

```
val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the UTC timestamp, and not the timestamp of the time set on the server?

Comment: The value depends on the system clock but the value is calculated since 1/1/70 UTC. From the JavaDoc "Returns:
the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. " (Note: I'm not at all sure that this accounts for leap seconds such as the one just added the other night. So I'm not at all sure that I would trust it for, e.g., astronomical calculations.)

Comment: @LarryOBrien it seems it depends on the underlying OS to take leap-seconds into account, but from the `Date` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) "Most computer clocks are not accurate enough to be able to reflect the leap-second distinction."

Comment: Don't think leap seconds matter in Unix timestamps. The millis timestamp keeps going forward 1000 per second regardless of what humans say or do with their AM or PM, etc.

Comment: oops looks like I'm wrong — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539436/

Answer (score 41):

As of Java 8 it's possible to do so like so:

```
import java.time.Instant
unixTimestamp : Long = Instant.now.getEpochSecond
```

Via micha's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703573/577199

Comment: I think this may be outdated. I'm not seeing the option for this method on that class.