# How do I round down an epoch timestamp to the nearest minute in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'd like to round down/floor an epoch/Unix timestamp so as to remove the seconds.

I'm using Python 2.x and Python 3.x

E.g.

```
1488728901 = Sun, 05 Mar 2017 15:48:21 GMT
```

to:

```
1488728880 = Sun, 05 Mar 2017 15:48:00 GMT
```

There's some great answers by using `datetime` to manipulate the time but it seems OTT if my input and output are integers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple bit of maths:

```
int(timestamp//60 * 60)
```

(`//` replicates Python 2.x division (`/`) where the result is a whole number)

Comment: In case this seems too simplistic: this works because Unix timestamps increase with 86400 every day. This is true for days including [leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539436/unix-time-and-leap-seconds) as well. @alastair I am sure that you already knew this - just added this for the benefit of other skeptics finding this answer.

Comment: Love it! Super simple!

Comment: As @bohrax alluded to, you can do the same thing with hours, days, etc. e.g. `(int(time.time()) // 86400) * 86400`

Comment: @Cfomodz, doesn't seem to work:  `>>> t = int(time.time())
>>> print( datetime.fromtimestamp(t) )
2023-05-25 21:32:24
>>> print( datetime.fromtimestamp( (t//86400) * 86400 ) )
2023-05-25 20:00:00
`

Comment: Expected to see `2023-05-25 00:00:00`

Comment: @mrbrahman this actually took me a minute to figure out haha. So that *is* correct actually... https://www.epochconverter.com/ in GMT so if you want to round down to the day (this morning at 00:00:00) then you will need to round down to the day (shown above), and then adjust for time zone depending on, well, your time zone, but that *is* the correct timestamp for today at 00:00:00... GMT

Comment: @mrbrahman ahhhhh, yes, as I was writing my answer I realized the issue here and why this problem isn't present for rounding (flooring) to minute. //60 doesn't touch hours, and thus is timezone independent, but flooring to day *does* touch hours, and thus you end up in GMT

Comment: Ah! timezones! Thanks for taking a look. This is the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

Or if you're not clever you could use **arrow**:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> timestamp = arrow.get(1488728901)
>>> timestamp
<Arrow [2017-03-05T15:48:21+00:00]>
>>> timestamp = timestamp.floor('minute')
>>> timestamp.format('YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss')
'2017-Mar-05 15:48:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do one thing here lets suppose col has your unix value. `modified_value=((col+30*1000)/60*1000).cast("long")` -- it will be decimal or integer covert it into proper integer if

```
modified_value_final = modified_value*60*1000

Example val=1488728901
modifeid_value=(1488728901+30000)/60000 = 24,812.64835
modified_value = 24,812 --after casting to long
final_modified_value = 24812*60000=1,488,720,000
```