# Can a golang RFC3339Nano timestamp be reliably converted to and from a Unix timestamp?

Tags: go, time, unix-timestamp, rfc3339, leap-second

In my golang application I'm using a Unix second-resolution timestamp (generated with `time.Now().UTC().Unix()`) as part of a salt in the hash function used for request authentication.

There's a desire to store this timestamp in a datastore, where the convention is RFC3339 nanosecond-resolution timestamp strings generated by the golang [RFC3339Nano function](https://golang.org/pkg/time/), along with the hash for authentication.

The question: Is there any risk that the RFC3339Nano can't be reversed exactly to the original Unix timestamp, in the event that the hash needs to be reauthenticated later?

I know there are some issues with [leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539436/unix-time-and-leap-seconds) which apply to Unix timestamps; is it ever possible that round-tripping through RFC3339Nano will result in a different timestamp, thus erroneously invalidating the signature?

The RFC3339Nano timestamp and the Unix timestamp are generated from the same time.Time struct.

I'm inclined to think it will work since [leap-seconds spawn an extra 61st second at the day of their occurrence](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), which I expect would map back to the same Unix timestamp as the previous second. The reverse would clearly fail though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you suffer this kind of trouble with no reason, why don't you just use the Unix() directly store to the database and restore with that?

Comment: The convention of the service is to serialize all timestamps to RFC3339Nano format.

I'm willing to break convention if necessary, but I want a case for why it's necessary.