# How can I display Unix day (not seconds) in date formatting?

Tags: linux, unix, time, string-formatting, unix-timestamp

The date is approaching (in fact, 2022-01-08), when Unix time turns 19000-days old. Currently, there is a way (namely, `%s`) to display `Unix second` in dates, but there seem to be no way to display `Unix day` in date formatting. How does one display `Unix day` in dates? If not possible, then how to introduce new date formatting symbol (`%?`) symbol for it?

Why?

1. Epoch date is easy to compute just dividing `Unix seconds / 86400`, and works well as natural [decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time), where:

   1 **dYear** = `1000 days`, 1 **dMonth** = `100 days`, 1 **dWeek** = `10 days`,
   1 **dHour** = `0.1 days`, 1 **dMinute** = `0.001 days`, 1 **dSecond** = `0.00001 days`.
2. `Unix day` digits, unlike `Unix second`'s digits, approximate lengths of ordinary concepts of time with less than 1 order of magnitude, thus work well as `decimal time and date`, where:

For example, now is `Unix day = 18993.94830052069` means:

```
18993.94830052069
 \ \\\ \ \ 30.052069 th decimal second
  \ \\\ \ 48 th decimal minute
   \ \\\  9 th decimal hour
    \ \\ 3 rd day of week
     \ \ 9 th decimal week
      \  9 th decimal month
        18 th decimal year
```

`Unix day`, interpreted this way, has the benefit of convenience of use as natural support for [decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time), so some people use it and need it.

Ultimately, I'd like to know a path for incorporating this display of time as one of the supported ways of displaying date and time in *nix systems.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why is it in __bold__?  `there is a way (namely, %s)` What do you mean by "way"? What "way" exactly? Are you referring that `date` utility takes an argument `+%s` and with that argument __that utility__ outputs number of seconds since epoch? `Unix second in dates` "dates" is not an unit of measurement, unix seconds are in seconds, not "in dates". Could you clarify that sentence? `how to introduce new date formatting symbol (%?` "introduce" - where? To what? To whom? To me?

Comment: @KamilCuk -- yes, I mean the date utility -- `date +%s` displays the Unix second, is there a way to display Unix day with it? `date +%???`. For example, `date +"%Y-%m-%d [%w] #%j T %T Z"` is the traditional date, it works well, but what would be the symbol for Unix day (preferably, up to 5 decimal digits, or custom number of digits if possible).

Comment: `Unix day with it?` What is an "unix day"? Number of seconds since epoch divided by `86400`?

Comment: "write program" -- agree, and done that, but evolving the `date` utility, creating a PR to it (if it is not yet supported) looks like the right way. And, P.S.: removed bold from question.

Comment: `Unix day` = Number of seconds since epoch divided by `86400`? -- Yes, exactly.

Comment: The display of seconds since 1970 isn't included on a whim, it is a common way of storing and processing timestamps. Other than there being a cute looking value coming up, do you have any actual use case for your date format? Unix time is useful because a single 32- or 64-bit integer can represent a wide range of dates and times to a 1 second precision, which is sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: // Other than there being a cute looking value coming up, do you have any actual use case for your date format?

Yes, it's the the most straightforward way to bring support of [decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time) into systems at the display level. Unix seconds is great as they are basis for dates already.

Comment: Ok, so basically, I start understanding that the answer is probably along the lines that I should `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils` and edit `src/date.c` it in, then build, test it, make a PR, get it accepted upstream. I'll look into this.

Comment: Have you thought about leap seconds? (others have)

Comment: Since `Unix day` would be deterministically derived unit from `Unix second`, this time would inherit all the imperfections (such as "some timestamps are not real times, and some timestamps are not unique times") as well...

Answer (score 1):

> date +%s displays the Unix second, is there a way to display Unix day with it?

No, it is not possible.

> how to introduce new date formatting symbol (%?) symbol for it?

Download the sources of the `date` utility implementation that you are using and patch it with a custom modifier. GNU date (if you are using GNU date...) is part of GNU coretuils, see https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ . Date utility follows POSIX specification.

I do not have ever encountered any need for a "number of *days* since epoch with fractional part" format. I do not believe it has any practical usage. I do not believe such a formatting specifier should be added to `date`. I see no value in it over "number of seconds since epoch with fractional part" (`date +%s.%N`), it's just a change of unit. I wouldn't want those hard-working GNU developers that are giving their work to the world for free, for them to spend time on something that has no practical application. I would like them to they spent their time with their families or on other more important things. As such, I *encourage you to not take developers time*, unless you can *strongly* prove that the community requires such a formatting specifier for practical reasons.

Comment: Thanks, [KamilCuk], got it. It probably means that will have to bring in proposals to [POSIX.1-2017, IEEE Std 1003.1™-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/#:~:text=Base%20Definitions,-Introduction&text=POSIX.&text=Specifications%2C%20Issue%207.-,POSIX.,POSIX.) before updating the code, and look into this thing. Regarding the price of developers -- it's just one value to return in formatting (unix seconds/86400 trimmed to 5 places after decimal point would do), nothing of the sort of development requiring to support various fractions like in Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Based on `date +%s.%N` example, I conclude that perhaps the better approach to `Unix day` thus would be to introduce extra 2 formatting symbols - one representing integer of days, another, the integer representing fractional part of day.

Comment: The general concept of "fractional days since epoch" is not unheard of; [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is commonly used in astronomy and other fields.  Just a different choice of epoch.

Comment: Yes, yes, and some people use it, and need, related article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225353/what-do-you-call-the-number-of-days-since-the-unix-epoch

Comment: Note: it concerns only the [nstrftime.c](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/nstrftime.c), which is used by [fprintftime.c](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/fprintftime.c), which is then used by `date` util, which is called [there](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/date.c#L668), by providing "format" parameter. Would suffice adding bespoke format parameter.