# Android DateTime to 11 digit Unix Timestamp

Tags: java, android, unix-timestamp

I need to get current date & time and convert it to 11 digit unix timestamp.

Just like this site does:
http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

I googled a lot but all i could find was timestamp to date conversion problems & answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

does what you want. Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732043/1069068).

[System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) returns the time from the Unix epoch in milliseconds. As `1 second = 1000 milliseconds`, you simply divide it by 1000 to get the time in seconds.

Comment: that gives me -3 hours shifted time

Comment: This is measured from UTC, so you will need to account for the difference between your location and UTC time

Comment: thanks , i will consider that :) im using this timestamp to sync time on my diy smart watch here : http://youtu.be/9vAify_zYy8

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the Unix timestamp in milliseconds which you can convert to seconds

```
long unixTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manipulate the date, you can use :

```
Date myDate = new Date();
myDate.setSeconds(23);
long uTime = myDate.getTime() / 1000L;
```