# Time to live of a item in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am playing with amazon dynamodb no-sql database from past few days and wondering that if there is any feature ***time to live (TTL)*** of a item, so that when item reached at that value it
automatically deleted from table as per the ***TTL*** value, instead of doing manually batch delete item.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, Amazon released the time to live (TTL) feature to DynamoDb in Feb 2017. You just have to go to DynamoDb on your console. Select your table. Then click **Overview** and enable it there.

[image: Under Table Details]

[image: Manage TTL]

The TTL attribute should be your column/attribute that would decide when the row should be expired/deleted.

**NOTE:** The ttl attribute should be of number datatype(because DynamoDb doesn't support datetime data type). So it should be in **EPOCH** time format.

For example:
 - Linux Terminal: `date +%s`
 - Python: `import time; long(time.time())`
 
 - Java: `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L`
 - JavaScript: `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)`

Comment: Any ideas how to do this in java?

Comment: @Hassan : Use System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L to populate the column that is a TTL attribute.

Comment: Interesting... What if I put TTL in future? Say (java) `Instant.now().plus(28l, ChronoUnit.DAYS).getEpochSecond() / 1000`  - will it delete items in 30 days (28 + 2 from dynamodb spec)? Or I am wrong

Comment: Question. Does DynamoDB extend TTL after reads on an object during said TTL?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni, no, Dynamo doesn't change the contents of that key.

Comment: For java this can be followed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703573

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: AWS released DynamoDb TTL feature in Feb 2017.

Unfortunately, the answer is pretty short: No

As a matter of fact, DynamoDB has been designed from the ground up for simplicity. No fancy features.

Comment: You know what's funny? "TTL" is a reserved word in DynamoDB.

Comment: I heard this year they are coming up with experimental TTL

Comment: @SoulMan did they add it?

Comment: TTL support has been released so this is no longer the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, They have recently released this feature. Go through the documentation below
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-automatic-item-expiration-with-time-to-live-ttl/

Comment: Add some description here too, as the link you provided may not always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using AWS DynamoDB console like what is stated by [Manjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588445/5042169).

If you prefer to use a command, you can also use AWS DynamoDB CLI command:

```
aws dynamodb update-time-to-live
--table-name demoTable
--time-to-live-specification Enabled=true,AttributeName=ttl
```

You can check out this [article](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/how-to-set-time-to-live-attribute-for-amazon-dynamodb-entries-6b10ed16281) for more information.