# String value that contains a timestamp. Convert it into date

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL database. There I have a table which has a column called date. The type of that column is **String**. That column contains a timestamp value (i.e. **1370842140205**).

How can I select that value as a date? - **10.6.2013 5.29.00**

Comment: What kind of timestamp is it? It is not a unix timestamp.

Comment: I saved that timestamp in my database from the Java function `System.currentTimeMillis()`. But I saved it as a String (Varchar) in my database.

Comment: That's no use. `System.currentTimeMillis` is - well - system dependant. Change the clock on your system and you'll get a different value... You can't get that as a date reliably.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't understan what you are trying to say? I used `System.currentTimeMillis` to get the current time in timestamp format, right? I saved that value in my database as a String. Now i want to retrive that timestamp and convert it into a date. I think that should be possible?

Comment: That's just not the way to do it. Use unix-style timestamps, that's the normal way to store date and time in databases. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`date` / 1000.0)
from your_table
```

and remove the milli seconds from the timestamp with `/1000`.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14463)