# convert current date to unix time stamp via function: android

Tags: android, timestamp

I have simple calender function which gets the the current date time. I want to convert the Date to unix time stamp format before passsing it as json.

my code :

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                final String format = s.format(new Date());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "unixtime" in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java)

Comment: thanku for the help. , question solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple just add one line and add "unixTime" where u send json

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```