# Process ISO8601 timestamps with offsets in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: kettle, iso8601, datetimeoffset

In Pentaho's Data Integration (aka PDI and Kettle), I'd like to do some processing on dates and times that are in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and have <del>timezone</del> offset information. For example:

```
2013-07-26T18:00:00-07:00
```

As of this writing, it's known that [Kettle does not understand this date format](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-9887) (despite its standardization [26](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=15903) years ago and at least one subsequent [PSA](http://xkcd.com/1179/)).

How can I operate on this data without resorting to string parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This took hours for me to figure out, so I'm posting Q&A style to hopefully save someone else the trouble.

PDI ships with a transform step called [User Defined Java Expression](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Expression) (UDJE), which can take in fields and output the results of Java expressions on those fields. It can also access the [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Joda eats ISO8601's for breakfast.

The Java expression:

```
org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(dt8601)
```

will take in a field `dt8601` and leave you with a Joda [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) that can work with the date. In my case I wanted to [convert to Unix time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java), so my full expression was:

```
org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(dt8601).getMillis() / 1000L
```

For the other fields in the UDJE, "New field" is the field name you want to give to the results of this expression, and "Value type" must be Integer (which, in PDI, corresponds to Java's Long).

Separately, a couple cautionary tales about approaches that did not work:

- Using a "[Modified Java Script Value](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Modified+Java+Script+Value)" step. You'd think maybe you could use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), but all I got was NaN. There's a bunch of custom date/string conversion functions bundled with this step, but none handle timezones nor ISO8601s. I found the step's [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Modified+Java+Script+Value) lacking in clarity and examples and gave up.
- Using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(dt8601).getTime()` for the UDJE expression, as suggested in a [Pentaho forums post](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?142519-parsing-ISO-date-formats-with-variable-timezones-and-precision&p=341061#post341061) and an [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202300/134610). This makes use of an XML [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String)) and returns a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) object which you can further process. As the poster notes though, XML dates are only "[inspired by](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)" ISO8601. This will probably function, but I for one am tired of writing date processing code and want something that strictly conforms to the international standard.

Comment: Correct answer, but you might also want to consider assigning a time zone. Your input string specifies an offset from UTC. But a time zone is an offset *plus* a set of current and past rules about anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Call `withTimeZone` to generate a new instance based on the first but with the specified time zone applied.

Comment: @BasilBourque Great point. I've corrected the question to reflect the distinction. Since I'm not doing date arithmetic, I'll forgo timezones for this. BTW, I assume you meant [`withZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) instead of `withTimeZone`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure at what point this changed in PDI, but I'm able to parse an ISO-8601 datetime such as `2017-03-20T13:26:29.681-07:00` by specifying a a field as date with a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` (note that there are no quotes around XXX as there normally would be)