# How to test date created with LocalDateTime.now()

Tags: java, unit-testing, date

I have this class

```
class MyObject {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() { return this.date; }

    public void myMethod() {
        this.date = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

How can I test that the date is properly set? I cannot mock `now()` because it is static and if I used LocalDateTime in the test both dates won't be the same.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I didn't want to use powermockito though... Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could generate a date time just before calling `myMethod()` and make sure that this date is **before or equals** to the date returned by `getDate()`, something like that:

```
@Test
public void testDate() {
    MyObject object = new MyObject();
    // Get the current date time 
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
    // Affect the current date time to the field date
    object.myMethod();
    // Make sure that it is before or equals
    Assert.assertTrue(time.isBefore(object.getDate()) || time.isEqual(object.getDate()));
}
```

---

If you don't care adding coupling to your class a better approach could be to provide a [`Supplier<LocalDateTime>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) to your class as next:

```
public class MyObject {
    private final Supplier<LocalDateTime> supplier;
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public MyObject() {
        this(LocalDateTime::now);
    }

    public MyObject(final Supplier<LocalDateTime> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() { return this.date; }

    public void myMethod() {
        this.date = supplier.get();
    }
}
```

This way it will be easy to create a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) for testing purpose in your test case.

For example the test case could then be:

```
@Test
public void testDate() {
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
    MyObject object = new MyObject(() -> time);
    object.myMethod();
    Assert.assertTrue(time.isEqual(object.getDate()));
}
```

Comment: This approach is easy to understand and to implement and it works. Anyway I think it is not exact enough... For some cases this will be the way to go but generally I prefer Jon's answer

Comment: I understand it is indeed a good approach even if I personally don't like the idea to add coupling to your class just for a simple test case

Comment: I agree on that! To introduce a clock is debatable. As I said, I will use your approach quite often, but as an answer I think Jon's one is more general and precise...

Comment: check my response update, it is much more acceptable to me to use a supplier instead as it is much more generic

Answer (score 26):

> I cannot mock now() because it is static

Indeed - but fortunately, you don't have to. Instead, consider "a date/time provider" as a dependency, and inject that as normal. `java.time` provides just such a dependency: [`java.time.Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html). In tests you can provide a fixed clock via `Clock.fixed(...)` (no mocking required) and for production you'd use `Clock.system(...)`.

Then you change your code to something like:

```
class MyObject {
    private final Clock clock;
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public MyObject(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        this.date = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
    }
}
```

... or however you normally deal with dependencies.

Comment: This sounds good, even though we need to introduce a clock that actually is not really needed

Comment: @iberbeu: Well, it depends on your definition of "needed" - I'd say it's "needed to clearly express the dependency". You could introduce your own app-specific singleton and always use that if you really want, but personally I prefer to make it clear where I'm going to rely on the current time.

Comment: I know Jon. I could've accepted both answers but I had to choose... Let's see what the rest of the users find better

Comment: @iberbeu: The accepted answer will fail if the test occurs at the point of a daylight saving time change or if the system clock changes. I prefer to isolate my tests from the system clock entirely - and make the dependency on a clock clear.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should never create a wrapper class just for the sake of testing.
You can just test that your **date** field is not null and trust the library
**LocalDateTime.now()**
if you really want to test it you can:

```
assertThat(myObj.getDate())isCloseTo(now());
```

from assertJ
https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3.18.0-isCloseTo-Duration

Answer (score 0):

Update your class as below :

```
class MyObject {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public Supplier<LocalDateTime> localDateTime = ()-> LocalDateTime.now();

    public LocalDateTime getDate() { return this.date; }

    public void myMethod() {
        this.date = localDateTime.get();
    }
}
```

and in the test method update the supplier variable as below just before calling myMethod:

```
objMyObject.localDateTime = ()-> LocalDateTime.parse("2020-11-24T23:59:59.999");
```