# How do I auto flag related records in an arraylist based on date and time?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, java.util.date

I'm designing a simple covid 19 tracking system. The system creates Visits object that is stored in an ArrayList everytime a Customer(objects in ArrayList) visits a Shop(objects in ArrayList).

The superclass Details.

```
public class Details {

  private String name;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private Status status;

  // Customer
  public Details(String name, String phoneNumber, Status status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.status = status;
  }
```

I'm using java.time package to create the datetime along with Visit object like so

```
public class Visit extends Details {
    
    private String dateTimeFinal;
    private String shopName;
    
    public Visit(String name, String phoneNumber,String shopName, Status status) {
        super(name, phoneNumber, status);
        this.shopName = shopName;
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        dateTimeFinal = dateTime.format(dateTimeFormatted);
    }
```

My customer class constructor looks like this

```
public class Customer extends Details {
  
  private String password;

  public Customer (String name, String phoneNumber, String password, Status status){
    super(name, phoneNumber, status);
    this.password = password;
  }
```

My shop class constructor looks like this

```
public class Shop extends Details{

  private String managerName;
  
  public Shop(String name, String phoneNumber, Status status, String managerName){
    super(name, phoneNumber, status);
    this.managerName = managerName;
  }
```

I also have a Status enum in another file that looks like this

```
public enum Status{
  NORMAL,
  CASE,
  CLOSE    
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish now is, if a customer that has been flagged as CASE visits a Shop, all customers that also visit the shop within a 1 hour time range before & after automatically gets flagged as a close contact (CLOSE). I also want know how to create time&date that is not localdatetime.now, because I need to generate visits to test if the flagging algorithm works or not.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Details`? Is this a class you made? Could you provide it if so?

Comment: Yes I made the class, I've updated the post. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Don’t store date and time on a `String` in your object. Keep the `LocalDateTime` you have (or a `ZonedDateTime`). A formatted stirng is for users to see, not for keeping data in your program. You can always format the `LocalDateTime` when you need to display the date and time.

Comment: For how to test with times that are not now: [How to test date created with LocalDateTime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527752/how-to-test-date-created-with-localdatetime-now).

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the `LocalDateTime.of()` methods (found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)) to create a specific time.

To keep track of possible flags, one solution would be to keep track of the last risky `Visit` for a `Shop`, and each time a new visit is made to that `Shop` to check if it is recent enough, and if so update the `Status` of the `Visit`, `Shop`, and `Customer`. Use `LocalDateTime.minusHours()` to compare the times.