# How to Mock LocalDate.now() in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, mocking, localdate

I have object

```
object func1{
   def something(arg1: Int): String{
    // var date = something2()
    // Using date
   }

   def something2(): LocalDate{
      LocalDate.now()
    }
}
```

I want to write a test on **something** method, How can I mock something2

Comment: You should pass the `now()` function in as a parameter, as @Dima suggested. But if you _must_ use and mock static methods, [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) will do it for you.

I personally consider needing PowerMock a code smell, and avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test date created with LocalDateTime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527752/how-to-test-date-created-with-localdatetime-now)

Comment: No, I still not able write test

Answer (score 2):

You can't make static methods. So, you need to do something like this:

```
def something(val now: () => Date = LocalDate.now) = ...
```

Then, in your production code, you do `val foo = something()` as you normally would, but in your test, you can do things like

```
something(_ => new Date(0l)) shouldBe foo
```

or

```
val date = mock[Function0[Date]]
when(date.apply()).thenReturn(new Date(0l))
something(date) shouldBe foo
```

Comment: Can you please explain bit more

Comment: What's unclear?

Comment: something method in tests, how are mocking?

In smoething method I have other parameters too. 

I am updating exactly in the question

Comment: Pass other parameters in as well. It's ok to have several parameters.

Comment: something(_ => new Date(0l)) shouldBe foo

In this line, Date(0l), in Date I can give LocalDate objeect right? 
And what should be my foo, expected value?

Comment: The expected value should be the value you expect your function to return. You can use `LocalDate`, yeah ... but if you do, that kinda defeats the purpose of your question - nothing to "mock", your function is _already_ using `LocalDate`.

Comment: class func1 extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {

  "testing " should "be generated" in {
    
     val startOfMarch = LocalDate.of(2022, Month.MARCH, 1) 
      something(_ => new Date(startOfMarch, int_value)) shouldBe "my expected answer"
  }
}

Would this work?

Comment: No idea ... Try it :)

Comment: Can you please check the description once

Comment: Sure. I can even check it twice!

Answer (score 0):

If the code's functionality depends on the time, it's definitely recommended that you have a second look at the code you're testing and explicitly pass a `Clock` as a parameter or something along those lines (e.g. a function as suggested in other comments) to make its behavior easy to test.

If you are testing this to make sure that a field somewhere indeed contains the time returned by `LocalDate.now()` please consider that you might be testing the behavior of `LocalDate` rather than your own code's, so probably mocking that doesn't really give you anything.

If timing is fundamental to the function's behavior *and* you have no control over it, I believe you might somehow use Mockito's ability to mock static objects. I came up with the following which compiles, but I'm not sure about whether it works or not (since I believe it relies on some bytecode manipulation black magic which might make your testing suite brittle, so beware):

```
import scala.util.{Try, Using}
import java.time.{Clock, Instant, LocalDate, ZoneId}
import org.mockito.Mockito._

def withClock[A](clock: Clock)(f: => Unit): Try[Unit] = {
  Using(mockStatic(classOf[LocalDate])) { mocked =>
    mocked.when(() => LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(LocalDate.now(clock))
    f
  }
}

withClock(Clock.fixed(Instant.ofEpochMilli(42), ZoneId.of("UTC"))) {
  assert(LocalDate.now().toEpochDay() == 0)
}
```