# How to test a date utils classes methods in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am looking for a solution for testing these methods especially for date util classes. I am adding my two methods that I want to write a test for.  How can I call the method at the end and how to doReturn the XMLGregorianCalendar when it has nested returns inside like the method I added?

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getCalendar() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    XMLGregorianCalendar gdateFormatted =
            DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(format.format(DateUtils.currentDate()));
    return gdateFormatted;
}

public static String getDateNowYyMm() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM");
    XMLGregorianCalendar gdateFormatted =
            DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(format.format(DateUtils.currentDate()));
    return gdateFormatted.toString();
}
```

My problem has been resolved, my test method is below:

```
    public void getCalendarTest() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        XMLGregorianCalendar gdateFormatted = DateUtils.getCalendar();
        Assert.assertNotNull(gdateFormatted);
    }
```

I couldn't succeed the part of XMLGregorianCalendar.

Comment: What does "how can I call the method at the and and how to doReturn the XMLGregorianCalendar when it has nested returns inside" mean? And I don't see any `void` methods!

Comment: @tgdavies I edited the syntax spells

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your question.

Comment: @tgdavies I added my test, I am just stuck at XMLGregorianCalendar part

Comment: You are using terribly flawed date-time classes. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` since they are notorious troublemakers. Unless you have a very specific need you may also not want to use `XMLGregorianCalendar`. Also to construct a string of `2303` for year 23 month 3 you are first constructing a `XMLGregorianCalendar` of year 2303 without a defined month. While it may work, it’s certainly confusing and ill-advised. Use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) that @BasilBourque already mentioned.

Comment: The nice solution: Use java.time and its `Clock` class in your production code. For testing inject a `Clock` the time of which you control. See [How to test date created with LocalDateTime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527752/how-to-test-date-created-with-localdatetime-now). The hacky solution: read the time before and after calling the method under test. Test that the time returned is neither before the former time read nor after the latter one.

Comment: Why are you focused on the legacy class `XMLGregorianCalendar`? One of your methods generates text in standard ISO 8601 format for the current moment — this you can do simply by `Instant.now().toString()`. In another method, you generate text for just the year and month — for this use the `YearMonth` class to represent, well, the year and the month alone. So I see no need for *any* of your code presented here.  I suggest you study [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) by Oracle, free-of-charge.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. `getCalendarTest` should simply call `DateUtils.getCalendar()` and check that the result is as expected (given that the date will not exactly match any other measure of 'now'). And what is the point of `privateConstructorTest`. Having said that, take the advice to use a `Clock`, and don't use static utility classes, they make testing of their clients difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see how your code is related to void methods at all, but if your functions return current date either as `XMLGregorianCalendar` or `String` and you are asking how to unit test them in the condition where current date is always changing then I'd pass the `DateUtils` via a constructor and mock the `currentDate()` function to return some specific date which could easily be unit tested.

Edit:

I just realised your methods are static. Consider making them non-static and wrapping them into a class which can easily be tested. You can create a static singleton of this class in non-test code if you'd like the benefits of a global static helper.

Comment: I added my test, I am just stuck at XMLGregorianCalendar part