# Convert from a Deadline to unix time

Tags: scala

Jeez, this seems like the easiest thing.

I have

```
def dueFromNow = 30.days.fromNow
```

`dueFromNow` is a [Deadline](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/duration/index.html), but I need it in standard Unix time.  Of course.  Like everybody else.

Cannot find it in the docs, the code, or online.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no any direct conversion. You can get Unix time in Java 8 [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703573/736957):

```
java.time.Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
```

So if have a `Deadline`, you can get its `timeLeft: FiniteDuration` and add to that value:

```
java.time.Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + 30.days.fromNow.timeLeft.toSeconds
```

It would be simpler to say just `30.days.toSeconds`, of course, if you have directly the `FiniteDuration`.