# Countdown with Unixtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to countdown on Unixtime 1635682066000. All examples on the internet are in milliseconds. I want to do this countdown over the Unixtime of the current time. I want to do this over the clock of the user's device. How can I countdown with Unix Time?

[image: The screenshot]

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "unixtime" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Do you mean you want a 1 second timer?  Or do you mean you want a timer to go off exactly at the time you specified and every 1s after that?  In the second case, that's impossible-  Android and Linux don't promise that type of timer granularity or exactness.  That's the kind of thing you need a real time OS for.

Comment: From the 1635547240000 Unixtime clock,
1635682066000 I want to count down this clock. I download real time from server. So I want to learn to countdown between 2 unixtimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Unix time then why you don't convert millisecond to Unix?

You can try this :

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732043/17219280)

Comment: Hello, I'm downloading a unixtime data from the server in real time. I want to make another data countdown with this data. This is real time : 1635549170000
This is the time to count down: 1635682066000

How can I show a unix time from real time as a countdown?